# Play after seeking currentTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to control html5 video with javascript. What I want is that when the user clicks on a button, the video will jump to another frame and keep playing from there. With my current code the playback always stops after the seek.

```
function jumpToTime(){
    var video = $("video")[0];
    video.currentTime = 160;
    document.getElementbyId("videoclip").play(); //not working
};

//the following code is probably not really related to the question:
var endtimeoffset = 2000;

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if (video.currentTime >= endtimeoffset) {
        video.pause();
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem, and found a solution by pausing the video, then setting the currentTime, then playing the video.  To update your code:

```
function jumpToTime(){
    var video = $("video")[0];
    video.pause();
    video.currentTime = 160;
    video.play();
};
```

Comment: Works, (I've just created the same thing), but will trigger further `timeupdate` events.

Answer (score 1):

Some things I would try:

1. in the jumpToTime() function, you have two different references to supposedly the same video (one obtained through jQuery and the other by getElementById()). Are you sure these reference the same video? To be safe, I would just call play() on the 'video' reference that you set the currentTime on.
2. This is probably a copy and paste issue since the console would complain if this was in the actual code, but you did mispell getElementById() (Need to capitalize the B).
3. For debugging purposes, I would comment out the 'timeupdate' event code, to make sure this isn't the issue and that this code isn't pausing the video after you update the timehead or call play. It probably isn't, since you are setting the current time to be much less than the offset you are comparing it with. It would, however, be an easy test to eliminate this as a possible cause of the issue.

Comment: Hi! This is embarrassing, but you were right about the B not being uppercase. But now that it's working, the video starts always from the beginning (not from the seek point).. Why could that be?

Answer (score 0):

```
function jumpToTime(){
   document.getElementById("videoclip").currentTime = 160;
   document.getElementById("videoclip").play(); //not working
};
```

getElementbyId --> getElementById -- b --> B

get direct object by id...

Comment: Hi! With this the play is activated, but it jumps back to the beginning of the video (and doesn't continue from the seek point). How could I get it to keep playing forward from the new time?

Comment: I mean that when I fixed the casing, the button started working but the playback doesn't continue from the seeked time but starts always from the beginning of the video. I tried to watch the example you posted at jsfiddle but can't really understand some parts of it like what is video = video == 1?2:1; doing?